# FILE* issue PPU side code

Tags: c

We are working on a homework on CELL programming for college and their feedback response to our questions is kinda slow, thought i can get some faster answers here.

I have a PPU side code which tries to open a file passed down through `char* argv[]`, however this doesn't work it cannot make the assignment of the pointer, i get a NULL.

Now my first idea was that the file isn't in the correct directory and i copied in every possible and logical place, my second idea is that maybe the PPU wants this pointer in its LS area, but i can't deduce if that's the bug or not. So...

My question is what am i doing wrong?

I am working with a Fedora 7 SDK Cell, with Eclipse as an IDE. Maybe my argument setup is wrong tho he gets the name of the file correctly.

Code on request:

```
images_t *read_bin_data(char *name)
{
    FILE *file;
    images_t *img;
    uint32_t *buffer;
    uint8_t buf;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    unsigned long i;

    //Open file
    file = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    file = fopen(name, "rb");
    printf("[Debug]Opening file %s\n",name);
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
        return NULL;
    }
  //.......
```

}

Main launch:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
   int i,img_width;
   int modif_this[4] __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) = {1,2,3,4};
   images_t *faces, *nonfaces;

   spe_context_ptr_t ctxs[SPU_THREADS];
   pthread_t threads[SPU_THREADS];
   thread_arg_t arg[SPU_THREADS];
   //intializare img_width
   img_width = atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("[Debug]Img size is %i\n",img_width);
   faces = read_bin_data(argv[3]);
 //.......

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Added code upon your request Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, if anyone else had issues with it you have to enable the upload rules and upload the extra-files you desired to be used by the simulator. :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly which line is failing,  and how?

You should look at [`errno`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) to see what error is being returned from fopen or other calls.

Also, it should not cause *this* problem, but you don't need the line:

```
 file = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(FILE));
```

That memory will just be leaked...